# mostrar um segundo options quando selecionado um determinado valor de um primeiro option

Tags: angularjs

Boa Noite,
Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema, em que dependendo da opção que o usuário escolher no primeiro `option`, aparecerá outras opções em um segundo `option`,

esta seria as opções no primeiro `option` no meu controller

```
$scope.teste = [
{nome : 'A'},
{nome : 'B'},
];
```

se o usuário escolher a opção A, tem que aparecer essas opções no segundo `option`

```
$scope.teste1 = [
{nome : 'A1'},
{nome : 'A2'},
{nome : 'A3'},
];
```

e se escolher a opção B, aparecer essas opções

```
$scope.teste2 = [
{nome : 'B1'},
{nome : 'B2'},
{nome : 'B3'},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

achei um exemplo exatamente como eu queria

http://jsfiddle.net/TsxTU/1/